# Is it secure to pass PIN via bundle/extras in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle

I need to ask the user to enter his app pin and confirm that pin by entering it again. I am not going to save that pin on the device and will sent it on server as soon as I get it.

While implementing confirmation screen, this question came into my mind.

> In rooted android device, if we pass data between activities using
>   bundle, then can some other app find out the values which are being
>   passed using bundle?

PS: We are using custom keyboard for taking input (pin).

Comment: no. rooted phones are not secured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On rooted device something can modify the framework to intercept Bundles so risk is higher than on non-rooted devices.